# Redirect 301 dynamic news htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I changed the URL structure for a website. Now I want to create a 301 rule in the .htaccess so if anyone is using the old URL via google for example it will be redirected to the homepage.

The old structure was /category/[article name] and sometimes /category/sub-category/[article name] now if use the following rule

```
Redirect 301 /category/ http://example.com/
```

It is only working when I type in /category/ wich is logic. So I tryed

```
Redirect 301 /category/(.*) http://example.com/
```

This is not taking effect. So my question is how can I redirect every URL when an URL is entered like my example above. So it doesn't matter what comes after /catagory/ it needs to be redirected so google will remove my URL's from the index and will index the new ones with the new sitemap I uploaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Redirect` like that, you would need to use `RedirectMatch` but sometimes it's problematic.

If you want to have more control and power over your redirects I would suggest using mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/?$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This will get you what you want and it always works for me.